# Backporting Qt 4.8.4: Circular dependencies of qtchooser

Tags: ppa, packaging, deb, qt, backport

I'm trying to backport the latest Qt packages (4.8.4) to Precise, using Launchpad. This worked well for the qt4-x11 packages but now I also need `qtchooser` which does not exist in 12.04. Trying to build it on Launchpad, all builds fail, as it seems due to the following circular build dependency:

```
qtchooser -> libqt4-dev -> qt4-default -> qtchooser
```

The build log can be seen [here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/157761679/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.qtchooser_26-3ubuntu2~precise1~shpmn_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz).

Is there any way to work around or properly resolve this issue?

My final goal would be to also backport the latest `shiboken` and `pyside` packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in this specific case what I had to do is:

- Create a new, empty PPA and get launchpad to build qtchooser there **first**, so it builds against the Precise version of `libqt4-dev`
- After `qtchooser` is built add `qt4-x11` so the latest `libqt4-dev` is built
- Rebuild `qtchooser` again against the latest libraries
- Continue to add the other packages to the ppa